# Android - set wallpaper to fit phone screen size

Tags: android, bitmap, scale

I am using a simplest code to set `wallpaper`:

```
Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.a));

getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(bmap2);
```

And the problem occur when image size is bigger than screen size. 
I can see only the part of input picture.

I tried resizing methods like `createScaledBitmap` and it works, but not like I want.
`createScaledBitmap` is resizing bitmap, but not size of picture, just resolution (just mess up the quality of picture, not picture size loaded to phone as wallpaper).

Does anyone know how to scale down the size of image, not a resolution?

EDIT:

Few screens:

Images from menu, before scale and after scale:

http://zapodaj.net/14097596e4251.png.html

So as you can see there is only scaled resolution, not size of picture.

Any ideas??

Comment: As a note, `setWallpaper` is deprecated since API level 5. You might want to look into [WallpaperManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html) which has many utilities.

Comment: I also tried:
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bmap2);
but it's the same. (at least result)

Comment: Already solved problem. That code helped me:

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
  getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

  int height = metrics.heightPixels;

  int width = metrics.widthPixels;

  Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap
    .createScaledBitmap(whatever, width, height, true);

Answer (score 16):

Answer from the author is in the comments,
but as nobody see comments, I copy it here:

```
Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.paper));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap2, width, height, true); 

WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
 try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: My image size is 600x800 and i want to fit in any device. your code is not work for tablet

Comment: @PratikButani you find any solution how to fit image on screen. Please help me.

Comment: @JohnR I didn't get yet

Comment: @PratikButani I also want to set image as wallpaper and I want this image to fit every screen size. But this solution not working fine. You have any solution?

Comment: @PratikButani http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759358/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-device-screen