# Wallpaper not properly fit on device screen

Tags: android, wallpaper

I have one set of images in one drawable folder. I have one button to set image as wallpaper on device screen. But when I set this image as wallpaper its either zoom or cropped. I want image should fit on screen size. I have seen lots of links on SO but no link is work for me. This is the code I am trying so far.

Code-

```
Bitmap bmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mThumb[position]));
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap2, width, height, true); 
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
  } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I also added following lines in manifest-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

Comment: i've also face same problem of zooming wallpaper. What you find solution for this please help me for solving this [problem] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201161/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-samsung-devices) ....

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hello This is working with drawable image i have checked it..

```
                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
                int width = metrics.widthPixels;
                Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
                WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
                wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
                wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                try {
                  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Also mention these permissions in Manifest.xml..

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

This is screenshot..

[image]

For reset Fit wallpaper of screen store the image path in shared preferences and use Boot Completed Receiver then reset the same wallpaper on the screen....

The broadcast receiver is..

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String TAG="BootReceiver";

@Override public void onReceive(Context context,Intent intent){
    try{
            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
            WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
            int width = metrics.widthPixels;
            Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.img);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
            WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context); 
            wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
            wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
            try {
              wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
              } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

After Add these lines in Manifest.xml

```
       <receiver
            android:name=".BootReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Hii @John R if you are satisfied with my code then accept my answer..otherwise let me know please...

Comment: You did this so late.bounties are expired.. :( i loose 100 reputation s.@John R

Comment: I found one difficulty in your code if i restart my device or after playing game back to home screen size of wallpaper increases. How to stop this?

Comment: increase in the sense??the size of wallpaper became zoomed or anything else?

Comment: And i think both the code here you gave the bounties and mine code are same and both are working same.

Comment: Is there any way to stop it zooming? I want permanent look as in above image.

Comment: you answered your own question. why I awarded that bounty to that user. Because your and his answer are same and he answered before you.

Comment: Please dont mind. This site is for helping others. Thats more valuable thing than points and I think you earned 95 points from this answer. Now check its 105 more than bounty.

Comment: thanks.its ok.it does'nt matter.u can join android coders chat room i m there can talk better.

Comment: please tell me the solution.

Comment: but what about other problem if I play a game and then back to home screen in this case image size zoom also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50774/discussion-between-john-r-and-android-guru)

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma i've also face this problem but this code not work for me please guide me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201161/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-samsung-devices

Answer (score 3):

try this code

```
Bitmap bmap2 =BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(mThumb[position]));
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmap2, width, height, true); 
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
    wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
    wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
    try {
      wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
      } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: what issue you are facing

Comment: On restarting device or after playing a game when I back to home screen. Image get zoom.

Comment: device restart could be handled by the answer of android guru, but change in device orientation would have same effect you are getting after playing a game. Do you have any app doing the same task as you require?

Comment: code by AndroidGuru not working on device restart.And I have fixed orientation its portrait.

Comment: @JohnR I think we have missed something very important about the method suggestDesiredDimensions() : "For use only by the current home application, to specify the size of wallpaper it would like to use. This allows such applications to have a virtual wallpaper that is larger than the physical screen, matching the size of their workspace.
This is for home screens to tell what size wallpaper they would like. <b>Nobody else should be calling this! Certainly not other non-home-screen apps that change the wallpaper. </b>" refer to description of method  suggestDesiredDimensions ()

Comment: Read description of suggestDesiredDimensions() method carefully here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#suggestDesiredDimensions%28int,%20int%29

Comment: So what's the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have image URL then use :

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
InputStream ins = new URL("absolute/path/of/image").openStream();
wpm.setStream(ins);
```

If you have image URI then use

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
wpm.setResource(Uri.of.image);
```

In your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"></uses-permission>
```

and don't forget to place this code in `AsyncTask`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public void changeWallpaper(String path) {
        FileInputStream is;
        BufferedInputStream bis;
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager;
        Drawable wallpaperDrawable;
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
            wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getActivity());
            wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
            wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

In this example , I have used image from my `device SD` card...

It's perfectly worked for me..

Comment: I have images in drawable so how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

notice: maybe not work for you.

you need this:

```
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this); 
             try {
              wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);

              wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

[enter link description here](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/how-to-set-wallpaper-in-android.html#comment-form)