# Wallpaper not properly fit on Samsung devices

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, wallpaper

I want to set wallpaper through app for all device but problem is that my following approach work for **Moto, sony, micromax** but not properly fit for **any samsung** device like **samsung S3, samsung duos, Tab** etc, in these devices wallpaper is much zoom see in screenshots.

please guide me for solve this problem.

```
private void setMyWallpaper() {

    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager
            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    // get the height and width of screen
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;

    Drawable drawable = null;

    if (who.equals("color"))
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(colorWallpaper[i]);
    else
        drawable = getResources().getDrawable(grayWallpaper[i]);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();

    Bitmap wallpaper = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height,true);
    myWallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
    try {
        myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
        Log.i("Wall", "Wallpaper set successfully ");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Micromax canvas screenshot :-
[image: Micromax canvas screenshot]

Samsung S3 screenshot :
[image: Samsung S3 screenshot]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759358/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-device-screen

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have tried this code already but still have a problem...... one thing can you explain me that why there they use receiver....

Comment: @Garg's I think there is image re-size issue with you.please check the width and height of image and screen

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma sir i have use 720X1280 size image in drawable resource and in samsung s3 this screen size height and width get in Log cart.

Comment: @Garg's u need to put higher resolution image for that.u can share your code on my email.pankaj.sharma101987@gmail.com

Comment: @Pankaj Sharma sir i have send you code please receive it....

Comment: @Garg's have got your code will check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem using call INTENT in place of `WallpaperManager` like this:

//load file

```
File file = new File(getGalleryPath());

if ( file.exists()) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_ATTACH_DATA);
     intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
     intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/jpeg");
     intent.putExtra("mimeType", "image/jpeg");
     this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Set as:"));
} else {
     Log.d("TEST", "file not exixts.");
}
```

// method for getting Image path

```
private static String getGalleryPath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM + "/MyImages/IMG-20160326-WA0083.jpg";   
}
```