# Android Wallpaper Doesn't fit. (Overflows and crops automatically.)

Tags: android, android-imageview

My wallpaper application's wallpapers doesn't fit for all devices. Images are 1080x1920px and in some devices, wallpapers are overflows and crops automatically.

Here is the code that I use to set wallpaper;

```
img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                WallpaperManager wallmgr = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                try{
                    wallmgr.setResource(+ R.drawable.a1);
                } catch (IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

What can I do to fit images ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap tempbitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tempbitMap,width,height, true);
WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
wallpaperManager.setWallpaperOffsetSteps(1, 1);
wallpaperManager.suggestDesiredDimensions(width, height);
try {
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Question was answered really long ago if i am not mistaking?

[android wallpapermanager fit screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759358/wallpaper-not-properly-fit-on-device-screen)

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't realize it. Thanks, it worked...

Comment: It didn't required clarification. Comment was just to thank me.