# How do I center an Android wallpaper bitmap with WallpaperManager?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-bitmap, android-wallpaper

The code I am using to set a background to a bitmap is

```
wallpaperManager.setBitmap(result, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_SYSTEM);
wallpaperManager2.setBitmap(result, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);
```

However, the image is not centered and I believe it has to do with the `null` parameter, which accepts a Rect as `visibleCropHint`.

How would I set the `result` bitmap to be centered by X and Y?

Answer (score 0):

As [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager#setBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20android.graphics.Rect,%20boolean,%20int)) says:

> Passing null for this parameter means that the full image should be
>   displayed **if possible** given the image's and device's aspect ratios,
>   etc.

So can't guarantee image displayed fully.

Try this(from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358613/android-set-wallpaper-to-fit-phone-screen-size/16913952#16913952)):

```
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.paper));

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics(); 
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
int height = metrics.heightPixels; 
int width = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(img, width, height, true); 

WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(MainActivity.this); 
 try {
  wallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: This works, however, I don't want to distort the image. The above stretches the image to fit within the display, but I only want to position the image centered and crop what doesn't fit. Is this possible with `createScaledBitmap`?